# Changes made with chattr are not detected by auditd

Tags: linux, audit, linux-audit

I want to monitor a particular directory using auditd, so that any changes are logged. I've created a rule using:

```
auditctl -w /etc/my_path_to_monitor -p wa -k my_rule
```

This works great for everything I've tested so far, *except* changes made with `chattr`, such as:

`chattr +S /etc/my_path_to_monitor/a_file`

The use of `chattr` isn't resulting in any auditd log messages - how can I have such changes audited with auditd?

UPDATE: I found an [ancient thread](http://linux-audit.redhat.narkive.com/b1PY6zLF/auditing-the-chattr-command-ioctl-syscall) about auditd not logging `chattr` syscalls. It does get auditd logging the calls, but it doesn't relate them to the files they affect - so I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I read the manual, came to the same conclusion for configuration, and got the same result for logging. Experimenting, I found that the goal can be achieved with the following configuration.

```
auditctl -w /etc/my_path_to_monitor -p warx -k my_rule
```

To offer an additional resource for `audit`, should you intend to further configure `audit`, the [RedHat Security Technical Implementation Guide](https://stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_6/2017-04-28/) (STIG) produced by Defense Information Systems Agency (DISA) has an excellent baseline of `audit` rules. These are still mostly applicable to whichever distribution Linux you might be using, perhaps with a bit of interpolation to match the system with which you are working.

Comment: That's odd that you detected changes by adding logging for *read* and *execute*. I purposely don't want to enable *read* logging, because it will produce far too many logs. Do you know why the `rx` options pick up attribute changes?

Comment: Sorry, no. I do not understand why it works.